# Percentage size of the rectangle over the inner rectangle

Tags: php, math, geometry

I need to know how much I need to zoom the inner box to rotate the outer rectangle 12 degrees and he touched the inner rectangle with four sides on the perimeter.

For example, i have image 400x300px.

In this image in photoshop, i rotated inner rectangle 12 degrees and zoom width on 113%, and height on 126% (how see my eye).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?  We need to see some effort.

Comment: i draw this image in photoshop. i dont have code on any programming language.

Comment: That's exactly my point.  You've done nothing beyond providing the problem.  What steps have you taken towards a solution?

Comment: draw image in photoshop and given parametres. sorry, i'm not study math. and just want how i can take percents zoom in the inner rectangle.

Comment: Do you intend to develop a program for this, or are you just interested in the math required?

Comment: if i can take math solution, i try write program on php.

Comment: This could be a good place for math-related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you friend for this url. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a math major and I don't know if there's a better way of solving this, but here's how I would go about it.

Let's take a look at this figure:

[image]

You know for a fact that all of those triangles are right triangles with 
every ∠Z being equal to 90 degrees.  You know for a fact that every ∠X will equal to 12 degrees because that's your angle of rotation.  Therefore, 180 - (90 + 12) leaves you with every ∠Y being equal to 78 degrees. Therefore, all of your angles are easily calculated.  You will know what your sides of the original rectangle are, therefore, you know what the hypotenuse of each of the triangles is.  This makes it very easy to solve for the remaining sides using this formula:

```
sin∠N = opposite/hypotenuse
```

As an example, let's say that we're solving for the left side of the top triangle.  Let's call it F.  Here's how it would look:

```
sin∠12 = F/A
0.208 =  F/A
A(0.208) = F
... and so on...
```

12, in this case is ∠X.  The side opposite of it is F, which is what we were looking for.

You only need to solve for one pair of adjacent triangles, since the other will mirror the results.  Once you know the length of the top side of the top triangle, for example, and the length top side of the right triangle, you can combine the two to get the total length.  Perform a similar calculation for either a left or right side.  If you know the values of the outer triangle, instead of the inner, by default, then perform calculations based on those defaults.  Once you know the other triangle's dimensions, you can calculate the difference.

I don't know if my example is the most efficient way of doing this, but it's easy for me to understand.  Hope it helps.